# postgres SQL: getting rid of NA while migrating data from csv file

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am migrating data from a "csv" file into a newly created table named fortune500. the code is shown below

> 

```
CREATE TABLE "fortune500"(
    "id" SERIAL,
    "rank" INTEGER,
    "title" VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" VARCHAR,
    "ticker" CHAR(5),
    "url" VARCHAR,
    "hq" VARCHAR,
    "sector" VARCHAR,
    "industry" VARCHAR,
    "employees" INTEGER,
    "revenues" INTEGER,
    "revenues_change" REAL,
    "profits" NUMERIC,
    "profits_change" REAL,
    "assets" NUMERIC,
    "equity" NUMERIC
);
```

Then I wanted to migrate data from a csv file using the below code:

> 

```
COPY "fortune500"("rank", "title", "name", "ticker", "url", "hq", "sector", "industry", "employees", 
                 "revenues", "revenues_change", "profits", "profits_change", "assets", "equity")
FROM 'C:\Users\Yasser A.RahmAN\Desktop\SQL for Business Analytics\fortune.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

But I got the below error message due to NA values in one of the columns.
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type real: "NA"
CONTEXT:  COPY fortune500, line 12, column profits_change: "NA"
SQL state: 22P02
So how can I get rid of 'NA' values while migrating the data?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a staging table that would not have restrictive data types and then do your transformations and insert into the final table after the data had been loaded into staging. This is known as ELT (Extract - Load - Transform) approach. You could also use some external tools to implement an ETL process, and do the transformation in that tool, before it reaches your database.

In your case, an ELT approach would be to first create a table with all text types, load that table and then insert into your final table, casting the text values into appropriate types, either filtering out the values that cannot be casted or inserting NULLs, or maybe 0, where that cast can't be made - depending on your requirements. For example you'd filter out rows where profits_change = 'NA' (or better, `WHERE NOT (profits_change ~ '^\d+\.?\d+$') to check for a numeric value`, or you'd insert NULL or 0:

```
CASE 
  WHEN profits_change ~  '^\d+\.?\d+$' 
  THEN profits_change::real 
  ELSE NULL -- or 0, depending what you need
END
```

You'd perform this kind of validation for all fields.

Alternatively, if it's a one off thing - just edit your CSV before importing.

Comment: it did work out using your recommnedation. thanks

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you out.